# Environment variables not getting set with vault file in ansible role

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

My playbook (`test.yml`) is like below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - env

  environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ access }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Hello"
```

And I get following error:

> TASK [env : Load VPC variables file]
>   ******************************************************************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field
>   'environment' has an invalid value, which appears to include a
>   variable that is undefined. The error was: 'access' is
>   undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/var/yogesh/test/roles/env/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, but
>   may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Load VPC
>   variables file\n  ^ here\n"}
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=1

My role (`roles/env/tasks/main.yml`) is like below:

```
- name: Load VPC variables file
  include_vars: "vault.yml"
```

This `vault.yml` looks like:

```
access: 1234
```

`test.yml` and `vault.yml` are in the same directory.

Now if I change playbook `test.yml` like below, somehow it works.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
     - vault.yml

  environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ access }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Hello"
```

I am not sure why is this happening. Can someone please shed light on this? Do we have to declare vault files in vars_files only? Is there any better/best practice alternative?

Ansible version: 2.3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The code is ok, the error is easily reproducible in 2.3.0.0.

**Solution**: stop using outdated Ansible versions. If you really have to use 2.3.x, use [Ansible 2.3.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansible/2.3.2.0).

Comment: Can't upgrade , will use vars_files. Thanks for your effort.